# cannot display layout after using camera activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout

I have a beginner's question: in my app I need to call a camera activity for results. In the method onActivityResult I do a lot of processing on the image just taken before by calling the camera activity. During the execution of the onActivityResult I would like to display a Layout (including a progressbar) but I can't. The screen stays black until the method finishes all image processing tasks. Should I use threads to inflate the layout while image processing is done in the onActivityResult method ? What's the best way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to use multithreading because `onActivityResult()` is executed on what is called the UI thread, that is the main and "default" thread. If that processing you do is too long, you get the infamous ANR dialog (Application Not Responding).

Android's solution to this is [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) should introduce you to this practice.

Comment: Great, using AsyncTask it works perfectly ! Many thanks to you, bigstones.

Comment: @CGM glad that it worked. remember, to accept an answer click the tick mark next to it, under the vote.